# Requisições individuais influenciam a velocidade do site em geral?

Tags: javascript, servidor

Bom dia!

Um cliente está no site, ele roda no console um código assim por exemplo:

```
setInterval(function(){
   console.log('Teste');
}, 1);
```

Esse código dele, rodando no navegador dele, pode de alguma forma prejudicar a velocidade do site em geral? Do servidor ou algo do tipo, ou vai apenas prejudicar a ele mesmo?

Esse setInterval foi apenas um exemplo, pode ser qualquer outra coisa, um `for` que vai deixar um loop infinito por exemplo.

Comment: Pode travar é o navegador do cliente. Agora, se ele fizer requisições excessivas ao servidor num curto espaço de tempo, alguns entendem que isso á algum tipo de abuso e suspendem o acesso daquele IP por alguns minutos.

Comment: Cara se ele etá fazendo isso pelo console acho que só vai afetar localmente, mas se ele fizer isso por um input, tipo um ataque XSS ai pode afetar sua página sim. As vezes esse artigo pode te interessar, é muito comum esse tipo de ataque em Wordpress e Joomla em versões mais antigas e com o PHP desatualizado http://www.redesegura.com.br/2012/01/saiba-mais-sobre-o-cross-site-scripting-xss/

Answer (score 1):

Esse código do seu exemplo executa localmente só no navegar do cliente, por isso não vai prejudicar a velocidade ou performance da aplicação no servidor nem para outros usuários. Mesmo que fosse um `for`, só irá refletir no cliente.

Agora se o seu código fizesse inúmeras chamadas ao servidor, requisitando uma página ou um serviço, api, etc, ai pode refletir na performance no servidor e para os demais usuários.

Em geral, servidores Web tem ferramentas para bloquear muitas requisições vindas de um mesmo IP por exemplo (que poderia ser um exemplo de um [ataque DoS e DDoS](https://www.infowester.com/ddos.php)), mas se não estiver configurado corretamente, pode até derrubar o serviço.